# Spring not setting statusText on response

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using some 3rd party stuff that is requiring the statusText on the response to be set. No matter what I do, it is just `""`. I am using **Spring** 4.3.4 and **Spring Boot** 1.4.2.

I tried having the `HttpServletResponse` as a parameter in my controller method and then call `sendError` like this:

```
public void foo(@PathVariable String myVar, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
  //... other stuff
  response.sendError(200, "OKOKOKOKOK");
}
```

However, when the actual response comes back to the browser, the response looks like this:

```
{"timestamp":1486068130749,"status":200,"error":"OK","message":"OKOKOKOKOK","path":"/my/path"}
```

And the statusText is still `""`. I know Spring must be generating this response before sending back to the client. How can I prevent this? Is there some way I can get a non empty string set for the statusText?

Answer (score 4):

I think you must be referring to the HTTP status line sent by the Servlet container.
As of Tomcat 8.5, the HTTP reason phrase is not written anymore, since it's not required and should not be read by HTTP clients: See [this Spring Boot issue for more details](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6548).

Comment: From http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html:
`RFC 7230 states that clients should ignore reason phrases in HTTP/1.1 response messages. Since the reason phrase is optional, Tomcat no longer sends it. `

Answer (score 1):

**1.4.2** version of Spring-boot uses an **embedded tomcat 8.5.6** in which the response text was dropped. So, you are getting statusText as "".

Initially the reason phrase was removed by **Tomcat-8.5**.
However, later a patch was provided to configure it with an attribute in the **Http Connector**.

All you have to do is set `sendReasonPhrase="true"`  attribute and it will work as before.

---

Use any of the below method to configure :

**Method-1 :** Update the *.../apache-tomcat-8.5.x/conf/server.xml* to include the attribute as below :

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" sendReasonPhrase="true" />
```

**Method-2 :** Configure through bean. (add in the config file)

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector ->
            ((AbstractProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setSendReasonPhrase(true));
    return factory;
}
```

---

**NOTE :**  This config will be dropped in **Tomcat-9.0** (ie : response message will not be sent)

**Refs :**

- [Bug Report & Discussion](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6036)
- [Tomcat documentation for configuring the attribute](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html)